# ExitNodes doesn't seem to work

Tags: exit-relays, atlas

I have the lines

```
StrictExitNodes 1
ExitNodes {us}
```

in my torrc, but when I go to a site that requires me to be in the US (in this case http://video.pbs.org/video/2365321775/), it still says that it's not available in my region. At https://check.torproject.org/ I see that my IP is 96.47.226.20, and clicking on atlas it says that I'm in the US. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily do any thing wrong. The IP 96.47.226.20 is the exit relay [bolobolo1](https://atlas.torproject.org/#details/9EA317EECA56BDF30CAEB208A253FB456EDAB1A0) which belongs to [TorServers.net](https://torservers.net/). Furthermore the country listing says United States. So everything seems right.

However it might be the case that NPR uses a geolocation database with old/wrong data. Here it helps to wait until your circuit changes and you use another exit relay. But they could also use a database where anonymous proxies are listed and block them. To be sure drop them an email and ask if this is true. Sometimes it helps to use open proxies or VPN connections with endpoints in the United States.

Answer (score 1):

[Atlas](https://atlas.torproject.org/#details/9EA317EECA56BDF30CAEB208A253FB456EDAB1A0) reports that 96.47.226.20 is bolobolo1, and lists its country as the United States. However, [What Is My IP Address?](http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/96.47.226.20) lists its country as "Anonymous Proxy". So does MaxMind. PHS probably relies on MaxMind, and definately not on Atlas.